# Infinite Window Loop

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, while-loop

I want to take a loop and turn it into a window. Using a while(True) loop to create the window. The loop I have currently adds 1 to a large number.

```py
def loop():
    index = 0
    while True:
        yield index
        index += 1

for i in loop():
    if i > 1000000000000000000000000000000000:
        break
    elif i < 1000000000000000000000000000000000:
        print(i)
```

P.S. this is only a joke for my friend

If it is possible to turn from printing the number to creating a window. Also is there a way to limit the amount of windows created, like the number the program is currently counting to?

Answer (score 0):

You can use simply use `Toplevel()` as a window. You can create as many `Toplevel` windows as you like :D.

```
from tkinter import *
b = Tk()
def window():
    global a
    a = Toplevel()
    a.geometry(f"1x1+{a.winfo_height() + 100}+{a.winfo_width() + 100}")
    b.after(100, window)
window()
```